# How to learn all these client-side tricks that are used on the Web today?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to learn JavaScript nicely and become very good at it. I want to form a systematic learning plan before I start reading the books. Don't want to end up wasting my time reading the wrong books.

I want to learn from books that will teach me enough to be able to learn all the things that are commonly used in today's websites.

For example, if you look at this website

http://rethrick.com/#

His page source doesn't show the full content of the web page. How does he do all those animated transition effects?

How do I learn all that stuff? Please help me. I want to learn all that stuff. Which book should I start reading?

Another example is the Stack Exchange websites. For instance, the Writers website itself. When you hover over the Questions link on the top or any of such links, it displays a yellow background highlight. How do they do that?

Where do I learn all these tricks? I see two options:

a) Look up the web on an ad hoc basis when you need to learn some trick.

But I don't like this technique.

OR

b) Systematically learn and read some books. I will read all the books if I have to. Please tell me what technologies other than JavaScript are at use to do these things.

And if it is just JavaScript, what books will teach me the level of JavaScript that Google employees and FogCreek and StackExchange employees use.

Comment: This question is not really SO material - but I will tell you that no amount of systematic learning will teach you to be innovative.  Part of that is being able to learn as you go, to invent things as you go, and part of it is just talent.  Not everyone can paint beautiful landscapes that sell for thousands of dollars, not everyone can create innovative web interfaces and applications.  Experience, constant learning, constant experimentation, and talent combine to create the things you see and like.  OR, you can get Firebug and copy what you see other people doing. ;)

Comment: Please start with reading a few [books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884/good-javascript-books), there are many tutorials out there that are at least weak or contain large security holes you won't notice when you still don't know about them. Good, recent books also cover things like DOM manipulation, CSS animations, using new elements like `canvas`, learn you how to use jQuery *after* you learned JavaScript, etc. Of course, as Chris said, there's no way to learn how to learn new ideas, just get inspired by other designs, also (or rather: especially) outside of the web.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the JavaScript books page, Marcel. That is very helpful. I already have JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, but the Amazon reviews on that are not very good. They say it is very heavy, has flowery language, very verbose and at places, it is almost like a rehash of some technical documentation. It is a good reference book but is highly overrated as a study book. True that?

Comment: Amazon.com dropped the older comments, so those are only regarding the newest (6th) edition, which I haven't read yet. But as you're already experienced in other programming languages, I think you'll manage. A more down-level book is Nicholas Zakas' [Professional JavaScript for Web Developers](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/047022780X?ie=UTF8&tag=nczonline-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=047022780X). Zakas is working on the third edition, at the moment. And if you want to learn some good, but heavy stuff, read [http://perfectionkills.com/](http://perfectionkills.com/)

Comment: A comment on the book lists- large percentage of modern-day developers never have read a book or taken a class on code. Most that I know personally have grown up being interested in computers and software.  I got started in GWBasic. There's a certain mentality or personality type that **enables** a casual approach to learning this stuff, a passion for it that makes it all intuitive. I don't think you can learn how to be an innovative developer, you either are or you aren't. You can learn every single language by rote and still not be as innovative as a guy who's never taken a day of college.

Comment: That is true, Chris. I don't doubt that either. I myself have had very little computer science education, but have learnt a several languages on my own. However, it would be naive to assume that anyone who asks a question about what books to read is an idiot and can never innovate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And if it is just JavaScript, what books will teach me the level of JavaScript that Google employees and FogCreek and StackExchange employees use.

This is the easiest to answer: none. Yes, get started with [Danny Goodman's tome](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101996) or [*JavaScript: The Good Parts*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) if you have some programming experience and want a quick intro, but both will only get you started. I mean, I'm sure they had some textbooks they read in college, but it's kind of like asking what books made pro athletes so good, or what book you read to get good at guitar.

It's maybe 10% textual material and 90% constant practice -- finding new problems to solve and figuring out how to solve them.

**EDIT**

I don't intend to imply that avoiding books is admirable, merely that experience is the best teacher, and that a theoretical understanding is only a means to an end: practical understanding. Books are absolutely necessary here; I'm mostly disputing the connection between books and the kind of expertise that lands you a high-flying job. For a perhaps more relevant example, imagine language learners. You can study the textbooks all you'd like, but absent experience you'll stutter like a first-year student. (Even if, for example, you can recite correctly the grammatical differences of some construction better than a native speaker.)

So no, don't just copypasta and come to SO when things break. But do start early in your reading, and the mistakes *you* make (rather than some script you copied) are often the best teachers.

Comment: There's a major difference between learning how to be an athlete or playing guitar and learning web development, especially JavaScript: the former is (mostly) a motion skill, which you can only learn by exercise, the latter is an intellectual skill, of which you should first know the basic concepts and conventions, before doing some exercise, or you will end up with many trials-and-errors (and lots of questions on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Thanks, Marcel. You were able to articulate my sentiment very well.

Comment: Also, thanks, Bryan. I am willing to put in the effort and I do have prior programming experience. I am just not a Web developer and have not practiced any JavaScript yet, but I know that if I get to it, I'll get very good at it. I only need to know which books to start with. I don't want to be reading the wrong books.

Comment: @Marcel Hence forwarding the asker to useful -- and very comprehensive -- books to get started. But while the amount of learning and the skill sets necessary are different, my point is merely that the key component of a systematic approach should be _doing_ (and also, intuiting the solution to a problem reflexively has a great deal to do with exercising your mind). Whether you read the best book or a merely good book, neither will do much without constant practice. (FWIW, I could mention human language learning. It's intensely intellectual but extremely dependent on practice.)

Comment: Point taken, Bryan. That's not under a debate.

Comment: Indeed, I fully agree with @WaterCooler; I only mentioned it because I think it's the wrong kind of example, that can trick someone in thinking like “Oh, I'll stop reading books, I'll just practice a bit using some copy-pasta tutorial I can find ‘on’ Google.”

Answer (score 1):

HTML5Rocks is a great resource, they show you some newer features and have code samples.

http://www.html5rocks.com/

Comment: Thank you. Very nice. Will keep checking it regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a nice project and start implementing it. Read books, search internet as you go.

So go make a clone of http://rethrick.com/